# Deducing the Heaviside-Feynman formulae from Jefimenko's equations

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electrons, maxwell-equations

I've tried to deduce the one point charge Heaviside–Feynman formula from the [Jefimenko's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations).
This should be possible, by replacing the densities with Dirac deltas, somehow, but I failed.
Could you provide it or sketch it?

Heaviside–Feynman formula:
$$ \mathbf{E} =  \frac{-q}{4\pi \varepsilon_0} \left[ \frac{\mathbf{e}_{r'}}{r'^2} + \frac{r'}{c} \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\mathbf{e}_{r'}}{r'^2}\right)  +\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \mathbf{e}_{r'}  \right] $$
$$\mathbf{B} = - \mathbf{e}_{r'} \times \frac{\mathbf{E}}{c}.$$
Here, $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are the electric and magnetic fields respectively, $ q$ is the electric charge, $\varepsilon_0$ is the vacuum permittivity and $c$ is the speed of light. The vector $\mathbf{e}_{r'}$ is a unit vector pointing from the observer to the charge and $r'$ is the distance between observer and charge. Since the electromagnetic field propagates at the speed of light, both these quantities are evaluated at the retarded time $t - r'/c$.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, and I don't have time to work out the kinks for a complete answer just now:

I've attempted to work through this by rewriting Jefimenko's equations as
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int d^4x' \left\{ \rho(\mathbf{r}', t') \hat{\mathscr{r}}\left[ \frac{\delta'(t - t' - \mathscr{r}/c)}{c\mathscr{r}} + \frac{\delta(t - t' - \mathscr{r}/c)}{\mathscr{r}^2} \right] - \frac{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r}',t')}{c^2 \mathscr{r}} \delta'(t - t' - \mathscr{r}/c)\right\}
$$
$$
\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r},t) = \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int d^4x' \left\{ (\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r}', t') \times \hat{\mathscr{r}})\left[ \frac{\delta'(t - t' - \mathscr{r}/c)}{c\mathscr{r}} + \frac{\delta(t - t' - \mathscr{r}/c)}{\mathscr{r}^2} \right] \right\}
$$
where $\vec{\mathscr{r}} \equiv \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'$, $\mathscr{r} \equiv |\vec{\mathscr{r}}|$, and $\hat{\mathscr{r}} \equiv \vec{\mathscr{r}}/\mathscr{r}$.  Note that these integrals are over $\mathbf{r}'$ and $t'$.  To see that this is the case, do the integrals over $t'$.<sup>1</sup>

It should then be possible to derive the Heaviside-Feynman formula by putting in the sources
$$
\rho(\mathbf{r}', t') = q \delta^3(\mathbf{r}'-\mathbf{w}(t')) \qquad \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r}', t') = q \mathbf{v}(t') \delta^3(\mathbf{r}'-\mathbf{w}(t'))
$$
where $\mathbf{w}(t)$ is the trajectory of the particle and $\mathbf{v}(t)$ is its velocity, and then integrating over $\mathbf{r}'$ before integrating over $t'$.  Doing this gives some expressions that are tantalizingly close to the Heaviside-Feynman formula, but there appear to be some stray terms as well.  I suspect I've just been careless with my derivatives and/or signs;  hopefully I will have some time in the coming days and be able to revisit this, straighten things out, and post a more complete answer.

---

<sup>1</sup>  True confession:  I actually obtained these expressions by writing out the Lorenz-gauge potentials $\phi$ and $\mathbf{A}$ in terms of the retarded Green's function and the sources, and then explicitly differentiating those expressions with respect to $\mathbf{r}$ and $t$.

Comment: Michael. I cannot upvote this answer since it is partial and temporary, but thx.

Comment: @MikeTeX:  No worries, I don't expect any upvotes for it — just figured I'd post it in case it's helpful and I can't get back to it soon.